# How do I make an awk program always use the same input file?

Tags: awk

I have an executable `awk` program that only operates on files with a certain name. How can I make it always open then same file so I don't have to type the name every time?

I want to be able to write

```shell
$ ./prog.awk
```

instead of

```shell
$ ./prog.awk filename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the `ARGC` and `ARGV` variables in the `BEGIN` block to change the files your program will read.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    ARGC = 2
    ARGV[1] = filename
}
```

Setting `ARGV[1]` will make `awk` read that file, and setting `ARGC` to 2 will cause `awk` to ignore any other files passed on the command line.